# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I newly started to code. Alhought Helloworld code, I get this error:  xamarin.forms.xamlparseexception: position 12:13 cannot assign property "click": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

The device that I want to debug king wear smart watch KW88-android 5.1.

code:

```
namespace HelloWorld 
{
    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("C:\\Users\\Gizem\\source\\repos\\HelloWorld\\HelloWorld\\HelloWorld\\MainPage.xaml")]
    public partial class MainPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {

        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));//Exception here!!!*****
        }
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.MainPage">

<Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       VerticalOptions="Center" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center" />
<Entry Placeholder="Write your name"/>
<Button Text="say hello"
        Click="Button_Click"/>
```

xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property to bind to is named `Clicked`, not `Click`. change your code to

```
<Button Text="say hello"
        Clicked="Button_Click"/>
```

and it should work.

**EDIT**

Alessandro Caliaro makes a very good point in that a ContentPage can only contain a single element. So you would also need to wrap your controls into a container, for example a `StackLayout`:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" >
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Entry Placeholder="Write your name"/>
    <Button Text="say hello"
            Clicked="Button_Click"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add your controls to a layout (Like StackLayout) otherwise other problems could came.